# Run shell_plus through PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Is there a way for me to configure PyCharm to run [shell_plus](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html) instead of the default shell?

I've tried putting the text of the manage command in the 'Starting  script' but then I get the folloiwing 
    django_manage_shell.run("/Users/cmason/counsyl/code/website/counsyl/product")
    import os
    import sys

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    # The new Django 1.4 default manage.py wants "from django..." before
    # importing settings, but we usually tinker with sys.path in
    # settings_local.py, which is called from settings.py. Importing
    # settings.py works but does mean some double importing. Luckily that
    # module does very little work.
    import settings
    # appease pyflakes; don't ever do this in
    # non-super-meta-namespace-trickery code
    settings

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line("shellplus")
```

and it hasn't really run shell_plus.

It seems like the 'Starting script' happens in addition to rather than instead of the default.

Shell_plus automatically imports all Django model classes, among other things.

Comment: I was able to get it to work just by using `shell_plus` as the custom run command.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't have the PyCharm command line completion goodness, and you can't use command line editing (up and down arrow for instance).

Answer (score 25):

I got the model objects auto-loading by hooking into the shell_plus code. I appended this to the default startup script in `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Django Console`:

```py
from django_extensions.management import shells
from django.core.management.color import color_style
imported_items = shells.import_objects({}, color_style())
for k, v in imported_items.items():
    globals()[k] = v
```

This was on PyCharm 2018.3.3 Pro

For completeness, this was the full content of starting script:

```py
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)

from django_extensions.management import shells
from django.core.management.color import color_style
imported_items = shells.import_objects({}, color_style())
for k, v in imported_items.items():
    globals()[k] = v
```

Comment: I had to add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with its value in the environment variables. Post that, this script worked perfectly!

Answer (score 17):

I've been looking for a solution to the same problem, and I ended up here. I tried solutions proposed by others, but none of those appeared to solve this issue. So I decided to find another solution. This is what I came up with:

The code block below is the original Django Console starting script of ***PyCharm 2019.2***:

```
import sys, django
print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django):
    django.setup()
import django_manage_shell
django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

Installing ***IPython*** and changing the last two lines as below gets it done in the most proper way:

```
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
from django_extensions.management.notebook_extension import load_ipython_extension
load_ipython_extension(ipython)
```

To make it work: open PyCharm settings (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and head to **Django Console** section. Then make changes in *Starting script* window and apply.  Finally, start the new *Python Console* instance.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm! (I also need to install `ipython` in my venv)

Comment: I worked on Django 1.8, Python 3.7 and django-extensions 1.7.4

Answer (score 12):

I looked at the source code of [`shell_plus`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py), and noticed you could use a method on a `Command` class named `get_imported_objects({})`

In PyCharm, go to: Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Django Console > Starting script

Add this to the existing code in that box:

```
from django_extensions.management.commands.shell_plus import Command
globals().update(Command().get_imported_objects({}))
```

**Note:** you may have to restart PyCharm to see the effect.

Comment: This worked on Django 3.1, django-extensions 2.2.3, Python 3.8

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this is to create a new Python run configuration. Set the target to module, and select the `manage.py` file for the project. Then put `shell_plus` in the Parameters field. Set the Working Directory to the project directory. Then lastly, set the Execution to `Run with Python Console`. Apply the changes, then run the new configuration.

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, but I found [this script](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4993#comment=27-432153) that at least loads up all the app models.  Put this in Settings > Console > Django Console > Starting script:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', stream=sys.stdout )
log = logging.getLogger("root")

from django.db.models import get_models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)
log.debug("Logging has been initialized at DEBUG")
log.setLevel( logging.DEBUG)
log.disabled = False

for _class in get_models():
    if _class.__name__.startswith("Historical"): continue
    log.debug("Registering model {}".format(_class.__name__))
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class

def debug_sql():
    from debug_toolbar.management.commands import debugsqlshell
    return
```

I also submitted this a [feature request to JetBrains.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116300)

Comment: Note get models is now deprecated you need to amend as per https://github.com/wq/django-swappable-models/pull/9/files?diff=split

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.7, following script can be used as a workaround with PyCharm 3.4:

File -> Settings -> Console -> Django Console and manage.py options

In `Starting script`, put:

```
import sys
import django
django.setup()

from django.db.models import get_models

for _class in get_models():
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: django shell run config]

This configuration works for me

Answer (score 0):

As `django.db.models.get_models` no longer exists, here's an updated version that will accomplish the same as Christopher Mason's version.

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', stream=sys.stdout )
log = logging.getLogger("root")

from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings  
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)
log.debug("Logging has been initialized at DEBUG")
log.setLevel( logging.DEBUG)
log.disabled = False

for _configs in apps.get_app_configs():
    for _class in _configs.get_models():
        if _class.__name__.startswith("Historical"): continue
        log.debug("Registering model {}".format(_class.__name__))
        globals()[_class.__name__] = apps.get_model(_configs.label, _class.__name__)

def debug_sql():
    from debug_toolbar.management.commands import debugsqlshell
    return
```