# Run manage.py shell_plus --print-sql in Pycharm Django Console

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-extensions

Is there a way to configure Pycharm Django Console to run shell_plus from django_extensions? In particular, I want to print the SQL for every ORM operation. I've tried this script, passing the print_sql options, but its not working. Thank you in advance.

```
import sys
import django
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)
from django_extensions.management import shells
from django.core.management.color import color_style
style = color_style(force_color=True)
# Default settings for shell_plus
shell_plus_default_settings = {
    'ipython':         True,
    'print_sql':       True,
}
g = globals()
objects_to_import = shells.import_objects(shell_plus_default_settings, style)
g.update(objects_to_import)
print(style.NOTICE("Python %s on %s" % (sys.version, sys.platform)))
print(style.NOTICE("Django %s" % django.get_version()))
print(style.SUCCESS("Shell Prepared. Enjoy!"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run shell\_plus through PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868449/run-shell-plus-through-pycharm)

Comment: Nope, thats why I made another question

Comment: Have you tried enabling it via settings.py config option ? `SHELL_PLUS_PRINT_SQL = True`

Comment: Of course, not working.

Answer (score 1):

here's one that is working for me. One thing that's essential is the order things happen -- do the shell_plus stuff before `django_manage_shell.run(...)`

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
from django_extensions.management.shells import import_objects
from django.core.management.color import no_style

globals().update(import_objects({"dont_load": [], "quiet_load": False}, no_style()))
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable SQL printing functionality inside PyCharm Django Console by utilising the monkey patch performed in `django_extensions.management.debug_cursor.monkey_patch_cursordebugwrapper` - simply activate the context manager inside your starting script (or in your currently open console) like so

`monkey_patch_cursordebugwrapper(print_sql=True).__enter__()`

Here's my entire console startup script:
https://gist.github.com/gruuya/e837b3037781c715185d409499fabd7d

Note however, that due to the fact that PyCharm debugger needs to display the variables inside the Varibles pane, Django queries are no longer lazy, but are instead evaluated as soon as they are assigned to a variable (you could circumvent this by e.g. creating lambdas which execute the desired query).